# NPM installing nested dependency when already satisfied by parent

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, transitive-dependency, tcomb

I'm having an issue with NPM installing two copies of `React` in my project.  Here are the relevant parts of the dependencies:

**My `package.json`**:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "0.12.2",
    "tcomb-form": "0.4.5"
}
```

**tcomb-form's `package.json`**:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=0.12.0"
}
```

I would not expect `tcomb-form` to get it's own copy of `React`, since I already have a dependency that satisfies its `peerDependencies`.

However, in `npm 2.7.4`, it **does** install a separate version in `tcomb-form/node_modules/react`, and this version is incompatible with my version (I use `0.12`, and it is installing `0.13`)

In `npm 1.4.28`, this behavior was different, and `tcomb-form/node_modules/react` would **not** exist, and it would just use my version.

Is there anyway to make it so that we all use the same version of React in the latest `npm`?

Comment: I did some tests with npm 1.4.28 and 2.8.3 and couldn't reproduce your issue with either. I suspect all the details matter here including perhaps your fully-specified dependencies, peerDependencies, and devDependencies. I don't have the knowledge to say exactly why each version does what. If you can post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we might be able to track it down exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm dedupe` should handle this. In future versions of npm, I believe this will happen during `npm install` by default, but as of 1.x and 2.x I think a separate dedupe is required.

Comment: Ah, yes, that removed the nested `react`.  Unfortunately, now I can't `shrinkwrap` after I `dedupe` because it has moved dependencies around, and doesn't think they should be where it put them.  Do you have experience with `shrinkwrap` after a `dedupe`?  I'll accept this answer shortly, thank you.

Comment: No, I tried shrinkwrap extensively and finally gave up on it as not viable in npm 1.x and 2.x. I think they are overhauling it for npm 3.x and then it might actually work properly.

Comment: Yeah, I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get shrinkwrap to work, and this is my second time trying to do so.  For now, looks like I am able to just dedupe react with `npm dedupe react`, and this doesn't touch any other packages, so I'm still able to shrinkwrap afterwards.  Thanks for the help.